# Android image to video

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

How I can load an image  as a texture and rendering it through GLES to use the MediaCodec Surface input approach?

I was started from EncodeAndMuxTest example.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at sample from [grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) ,it will give you insight about how you should do it

Here is code to load bitmap into texture

```
int mTextureId = -1;

public void loadTexture(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    if (mTextureId != -1) {
        int[] textureHandle = new int[1];

        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);


        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureId);

        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
            GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
            GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
            GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
            GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    } else {
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureId);
    }

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
 }
```

and here is how you can render it to inputsurface

```
// Create Fullframe rectangle (a class from grafika),
mInputSurface.makeCurrent();
mFullFrameRect = new FullFrameRect(new Texture2dProgram(Texture2dProgram.ProgramType.TEXTURE_2D));

....


// And when you want to draw it
mInputSurface.makeCurrent(); // if its not already current
loadTexture(bitmap);
GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
mFullFrameRect.drawFrame(mTextureId, GlUtil.IDENTITY_MATRIX);
mInputSurface.setPresentationTime(pts);
mInputSurface.swapBuffers();
```

`FullFrameRect`, `Texture2dProgram`, `GlUtil` are classes from Grafika, so you should copy it or implement similar functionality by yourself

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seems I'm on a good way, I tried your solution but I still get a black screen video. What I don't understand do I need a GLSurfaceView to render the image texture? Thanks

Comment: Ok. I was able to convert my image. tI was my fault, wrong configuration for Egl context. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @Siv would be useful to know what was your solution